# Navigation from one view to another view in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to navigate/redirect from one view to another. In this case I wrote following code.

```
var My_router = new my_router();      
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });    
My_router.navigate('contacts',true);
```

This is not working. What is the wrong here?? But below one is working.

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/contacts', true);
```

Which is the correct way of navigation/redirect ??

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `true` with

```
{trigger: true}
```

or calling navigate from my_router class, not object.